# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 10 help- Failing Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having some trouble with the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl.  I'm at the end of chapter 10 and getting a large amount of failing tests. I have compared my code with the github repo Michael put together and they line up.  Here is the failed test report:

```
  1) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing partial shared/stats with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/bobbysudekum/Documents/Projects/rails/Secondattempt/sample_app_three/app/views"
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2309319721249673303_70162631795520'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing partial shared/stats with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/bobbysudekum/Documents/Projects/rails/Secondattempt/sample_app_three/app/views"
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2309319721249673303_70162631795520'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing partial shared/stats with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/bobbysudekum/Documents/Projects/rails/Secondattempt/sample_app_three/app/views"
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2309319721249673303_70162631795520'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

     # REMOVED 43 more identical errors
```

#### View ported from github

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry about not including example code- went over the character limit. Please consult the rest of the code on github-  https://github.com/rsudekum/sample_app_three

Being brand new to rails/ruby, I do not really know what to look for in a failing test.  If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much obliged.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Without knowing the Hartl tutorials well, it is clear that you have no partial `shared/_stats.html.erb`, which you are calling in `users/show.html.erb`

Comment: Michael is right, there is such line in your `users/show.html.erb`: `<%= render 'shared/stats' %>`, but no partial `shared/_stats.html.erb`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/tree/master/app/views/shared) :)

Comment: Thanks for the timely responses.  I added **shared/_stats/html.erb** [see here](https://github.com/rsudekum/sample_app_three/commit/2372cc7fd97671c613d1c39e6a2c759587ce37e2) but it is still failing (47 times).  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please see my pull request: https://github.com/rsudekum/sample_app_three/pull/1

Here are my notes as I cloned the application and investigated the errors. Please note that I started my investigation *before* the comments to the answer were posted, so I may have noted things you already knew about. Regardless, all specs are now passing on my machine. I tried to make the application resemble the state of the tutorial at the end of chapter 10, but I've never followed this tutorial, so it may not be an exact match.

The first migration, `20120711232738_create_users.rb`, seems to have
had its entire file content replaced with the content for the
`20120714233631_create_microposts.rb`. (Accidental copy-paste?)
Reverting to its original content resolves the migration issue.

The partial in `views/shared/_stats.html.erb` was missing. Since
you said you had just completed chapter 10, and this partial is
not introduced until chapter 11, I decided to comment out the reference
to it instead of updating the partial itself, because the partial
makes references to things not discussed until chapter 11.

Ditto for the `follow_form` partial.

The `shared/feed` and `shared/feed_item` partials were incorrect
based on listing 10.42 and 10.47. I corrected them to reflect those
listings.

You forgot to assign `object: f.object` in your rendering of the
`error_messages` partial from `users/edit.html.erb`.

You used `confirm: "..."` in `users/_user.html.erb`. That's OK but
deprecated, so I changed it to `data: { confirm: "..." }` instead.

Ditto about `confirm` for `microposts/_microposts.html.erb`.

You forgot to add the code for `SessionsController#destroy`. This
is covered in listing 8.29. I added it.

Comment: sinisterchipmunk Thank you so much for your help! Works flawlessly now.